# Multiple Integrals - Evaulating as Volume of Solid

Tags: integration

We are asked: Evaluate the double integral by first identifying it as the
volume of a solid.

The problem is as follows:

$$\iint_R 3 \, \mathrm{d}A$$

where

$$R=[-2,2]\times[1,6].$$

The answer is:

$$\iint_R 3 \, \mathrm{d}A = (4)(5)(3) = 60$$

Why, how?

Comment: $\int\int_RdA$ is precisely  the area of $R$, so...

Comment: Ah, 2-(-2) * 6-1 * 3

Comment: Your last is missing parentheses.  In context, it is clear what you mean, but what you wrote should be evaluated as $2-[(-2)*6]-(1*3)$, because of the order of operations.  Even for personal use, it is good to be careful so you don't get confused when you come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to recognize that $R$ is a rectangle, of size $(2-(-2)) \times (6-1)=4 \times 5$ and the integrand is a constant.