# Multiple Integration - Evaluating Volume of Solid

Tags: integration

We are asked: Evaluate the double integral by first identifying it as the
volume of a solid.

The problem is as follows:

$$\iint_R (5-x) \, \mathrm{d}A$$

where

$$R=[0,5]\times[0,3].$$

The answer is:

$$\iint_R (5-x) \, \mathrm{d}A = 3((1/2)(5)(5)) = 37.5$$

Why, how?

Comment: I graphed it, and it is a slanted linear surface. I wasn't able to produce a triangle (pyramid). Even so, the volume of a pyramid is (l*w*h)/3.

Comment: Ah,  but it is actually a triangular cylinder with v = (1/2)(a*c*h). Without recognizing the volume of these fundamental shapes, I will always get the answer wrong?

Comment: This is virtually identical to the question you asked a short time ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1523582/265466.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this as a volume :
$$\int_{x=0}^5 \int_{y=0}^3 \int_{z=x}^5 1 dxdydz$$
which is the half of the $[0,5]\times[0,3]\times[0,5]$ volume